# Value of a four digit number

Tags: combinatorics

Let a four digit number be $abcd$ ie. $$abcd =1000a+100b+10c+d.$$ When the digits are reversed ie. $dcba$, the new number is $9$ times    $abcd$. What is the number?
I've tried making an equation using the given relation and equating different coefficients of powers of $10$  but couldn't reach anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thought: If a four-digit number is equal to $9$ times another four-digit number, the smaller has to be between $1000$ and $1111$, and the larger one between $9000$ and $9999$. So we already know the values of $a$ and $d$.

Comment: Hint 1: what digit could $a$ be, if $9\cdot abcd$ is still 4-digit? Hint 2: what digit could $d$ be, if $9\cdot d$ ends with digit $a$?

Comment: Don't really need it.  But $dcba$ is a multiple of $9$ so its digits add to a multiple of $9$.  $d = 9$ and $a=1$ do to "overflow" so $b+c = 8$ or $b+c = 17$.  Doesn't really help because once you know $d=9;a = 1$ you have $9001 + 100c + 10b = 9081 + 900b + 90c$  which is easy to solve as it means $c = 89b + 8$ which as these are digits is ... weird.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid "overflow", we must have $a=1$, which implies $d=9$.

Now,

$$1000\cdot9+100\cdot c+10\cdot b+1\cdot1=9000\cdot1+900\cdot b+90\cdot c+9\cdot9$$

or after simplification

$$c=89\cdot b+8$$

Obviously $b=0$ and

$$\color{green}{1089}.$$

Comment: To the upvoter: I have reworked, taking into account that $a=1$ implies $d=9$, which leads me to the solution by @drhab, much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

just do it.

$dcba = 1000d + 100c + 10b + a = 9(1000a+100b+10c+d)=9000a + 900b + 90c + 9d$

If $a \ge 2$ then $9*abcd > 18,000$ which is more than four digits.

So $a \le 1$.  If $a = 0$ then $abcd$ is not a four digit number so $a = 1$

$1000d + 100c + 10b + 1 = 9000 + 900b + 90c + 9d$.

$100c + 10b + 1 \le 991$ so $1000d > 8009$ so $d > 8$ so $d = 9$.

$9000 + 100c + 10b + 1 = 9000 + 900b + 90c + 81$

$100c + 10b = 900b + 90c + 80$

$10c + b = 90b +9c + 8$

$c = 89b + 8$.

Well... $c < 10$ so $b = 0$.

And $c = 8$.

So $abcd = 1089$ and $9801 = 9*1089$

Answer (score 0):

From $9\times dcba<10000$ it follows immediately that $d\in\{0,1\}$.

If $d=1$ then it follows that $a=9$ and we have: $$9\times(1000+100c+10b+9)=9000+100b+10c+1$$
leading to $89c=b-8$ and consequently $c=0$ and $b=8$.

So $abcd=9801$ is a solution.

It remains to check the case $d=0$.

Try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that There is two other conditions:

1 : 3 must divide the sum of digits of required number. So if $a=1$ and $ d=9$ then $3|10+b+c$.

2 : $b+c<10$

It is not hard to find these couples and see that only $b=0$ and $c=8$ satisfies all conditions, i.e $abcd=1089$ and $dcba=9801$